# If an element is not present ,it should be populated with the value of other element + xslt

Tags: xslt

My incoming XML

```
<images>
<image id="i1">
  <primary>true</primary>
  <height>120</height>
</image>
<image id="i2">
  <primary>false></primary>
  <height>120</height>
   <preferred>false</preferred>
</image>
</images>
```

Output xml expected

```
<images>
<image id="i1">
  <primary>true</primary>
  <height>120</height>
<preferred>true</preferred>
</image>
<image id="i2">
  <primary>false></primary>
  <height>120</height>
   <preferred>false</preferred>
</image>
</images>
```

"preferred" is an optional element,When not present in the incoming xml need to added in the output xml with the value read from primary element  .

Please help me with the xslt .

Comment: what version of XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of XSLT that you are using.

This will do the trick in XSLT 3.0.  For other versions of XSLT, there are similar variants that should work as well.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
  
  <xsl:template match="image" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()" />
      <xsl:if test="not(exists(preferred))" >
        <preferred>{primary}</preferred>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What makes you think the 1st template is required? -- P.S. I believe the 2nd template could be written more elegantly using a *predicate* instead of `xsl:if`.

Comment: I think that you are right, @michael.hor257k, that first template is implicity part of the "shallow-copy".  Editing my response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet which has a template to handle the case that an `image` has no `preferred` child, and a template to copy everything else (an "identity" template):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- add preferred element where missing -->
  <xsl:template match="image[not(preferred)]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <preferred><xsl:value-of select="primary"/></preferred>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```